# Загрузка с Яндекс диска URL фото в CSV файл

Tags: python, csv, яндекс-диск

Хочу создать программу для выгрузки общедоступных фото с яндекс диска в CSV файл, но не могу найти ошибку в коде. Чекеры тоже не помогают.
Подскажите, пожалуйста!

```
import openpyxl
import csv

try:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Excel_Files/EXctll.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.active

    cells = ['J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q']
    links = [str(sheet[cell].value) for cell in cells if sheet[cell].value]
    image_links = [link for link in links if link.startswith('http')]
    image_links_str = ','.join(image_links)

    csv_filename = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Test squad/CSV.csv'

    try:
        with open(csv_filename, mode='w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([image_links_str])

        print("Данные успешно записаны в файл.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Файл не найден.")

except Exception as e:
    print("Произошла ошибка:", e)
```

Comment: причем здесь вообще яндекс-диск и выгрузка фото?

Comment: Получение URL с картинки ( товара) так как ссылка на фото которое в диске, не подходить для выгрузки файлах в CSV формате

Comment: "Не могу найти ошибку в коде" - а почему вы думаете, что в коде ошибка? Если выходит какая-то ошибка, вы должны её скопировать прямо в вопрос. Если код не делает то, что вами задумано - вы должны описать в вопросе, что вы ожидали, и что в реальности получилось. Сейчас совершенно непонятно, в чём у вас проблема.

Comment: где у вас в коде вообще упоминается яндекс.диск и загрузка фото? я так понимаю, что вы пытаетесь из excel-файла выбрать все URL?

Comment: pyCharm выдает ошибку что нет файла xlsx, но он есть, и я не понимаю в чем дело, путь указан верно

Comment: @Элвин - "pyCharm выдает ошибку". Причём тут PyCharm ?! Вы запускаете программу, или ошибка появляется ДО запуска программы?  Почему Вы не опубликовали текст сообщения ошибки? Почему не указываете, к какой строке программы относится эта ошибка ?